# Azure DevOps Repository Strategy

Tags: git, azure, repository, devops

I am in the process of implementing Azure DevOps (on Prem) at my company and have a few best practices question.

**Small bit of Background:**

We sell a packaged product that consists of a handful of VS2019 projects (4 winform applications, 1 windows service, 1 rest api, and a handful of wix installer projects).  We do quarterly releases and distribute our product in the form of a handful of .msi's.  All of the development is done inhouse by 5 developers.  We plan on using the following Git branching model: https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model.  All  VS2019 projects are versioned and released together.

**Azure Git Repo Question:**

Would it make sense to have just a single repo to house the source code for all of the VS2019 applications?  This way I would only have to set one set of branching policies and permissions.  Doing release branching also seems like it would be easier using just one repo (I am assuming that if I had one repo per Visual Studio project, I would have to create and coordinate Release branch creation for each repo?).  It also saves time on repo setup and maintenance.  Is this advisable?  Is there a reason why multiple repos are a better option?
If the use of a single repo is advisable, how would we handle CI builds and builds when Pull Requests get submitted?  If the pull request is for code in only one application, I don't want to build the other ones.

Thanks in advance,

Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think multiple repostories is the way to go... When using a single repository you encounter many problems such as: long git clone time, CI gets complicated, a lot of merge conflicts etc.. At my company we also use azure devops and we have multiple repositories where we release weekly. Our release and CI is completely automated and we make a release automatically when a tag on master is pushed (we are using a fairly similar git branching approach to yours).

As every project produces a different output (.msi for the winforms, and probably .dll for the webapi) multiple repos is definitely the way to go. Using this approach you can also release products singularly (for example a hotfix on  the rest api wouldn't require a release on the winforms application etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am definitely leaning towards creating a separate git repo for each Visual Studio project.  Given the branching model that I would like to use, would that mean that I would need to create a Develop branch and Main branch in each of the Repos?  Also, when it comes time for us to start our release process, I am assuming we would need to create the Release branch in each of the individual Repos?  Is that how you do it at your company?  Did you create any kind of automation to assist you with the process?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. In my company we don't create a branch for each release, but we release directly from master (the hotfixes are also created on master). We don't really have any automation because a release like this is difficult to automate. We simply develop on the develop branch the whole week and when the release is up, we have a tool that shows us every repository that changed in this week (and needs to be released). Then someone goes through every repository, prepares it for the release (eventual changelog etc.), merges to master, creates a tag and pushes it.

Comment: We use the [gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) method without the release branches. We previuosly made release branches for every release, but eventually came to the conclusion that this was unnecessary overhead.

Comment: When you push to Master in each Repo, do you Create a Release tag in the Master branch?

Comment: Yes, we create a git tag on master. A server-side git-hooks notices that and runs the release pipeline.

Comment: Does your server-side git-hook monitor the Master branches in all of your repos for a specific tag to trigger the running of a Pipeline?  If so, if you tag two of your master branches in two repos at relatively the same time, will it trigger the Pipeline to run twice?

Comment: Our pipelines are always per repository. I don't know why you would have the same pipeline for multiple repositories. We do have task groups though (for example one for dotnet applications) which get used by every pipeline. But no, if we tag multiple repositories at the same time, multiple different pipelines start at the same time.